# Can Someone Explain Coverage of a Wrapper in a HttpRequest Callout?

Tags: apex, httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I have a class I've written that HttpRequest GET to an API and brings back lead information that I'm converting to Contacts (we use them as Inquiries).

I have 2 additional classes, one is a Wrapper class I use to deserialize the JSON response, the other is lets me turn my Wrapper into a list.

I'm using an HttpCalloutMock class to test it, and filling in a few static JSON responses.

Everything works, it's wonderful and my test results are 80% code coverage, but all the lines that aren't tested are all the lines in those 2 classes.

Can anyone tell me why the test ignores those classes?

EDIT: Here's some code:
I'm using the SingleRequestMock.cls outlined in this post, I'm also using the testMethod in that post:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html

requestmock:

```
@isTest
public class SingleRequestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    protected Integer code;
    protected String status;
    protected String bodyAsString;
    protected Blob bodyAsBlob;
    protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders;

    public SingleRequestMock(Integer code, String status, String body,
                                     Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
        this.code = code;
        this.status = status;
        this.bodyAsString = body;
        this.bodyAsBlob = null;
        this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
    }

    public SingleRequestMock(Integer code, String status, Blob body,
                                     Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
        this.code = code;
        this.status = status;
        this.bodyAsBlob = body;
        this.bodyAsString = null;
        this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
    }

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();
        resp.setStatusCode(code);
        resp.setStatus(status);
        if (bodyAsBlob != null) {
            resp.setBodyAsBlob(bodyAsBlob);
        } else {
            resp.setBody(bodyAsString);
        }

        if (responseHeaders != null) {
             for (String key : responseHeaders.keySet()) {
            resp.setHeader(key, responseHeaders.get(key));
             }
        }
        return resp;
    }
}
```

testclass:

```
@isTest
private class testrequestStudyAbroad101 {

    static testMethod void testrequestStudyAbroad() {
        Datetime dt=Datetime.now();
        String dts=dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
        SingleRequestMock fakeResponse=new SingleRequestMock(200,'OK','[{/**FAKE STATIC JSON HERE**/}]', null);
        Test.setMock(HttpCallOutMock.class, fakeResponse);
        requestStudyAbroad101.getInq();
    }
}
```

The "uncovered" wrappers:

```
public class saJSON {
    public List<saJSONwrapper> saJSON;
}

public class saJSONwrapper {
    String id;  
    String email; 
    String name; //contact.name breaks out into firsname lastname
    String university; 
    String comment; 
    String address; //mailing address breaks out to mailing street, mailing city, mailing state, maling zip, mailing country
    String program_id; //need to map
    String program_name; 
    String program_link; 
    String created_at_string; 
    String catalog_requested; //make a task
    String phone_call_requested; //make a task
    String phone_number; 
    String lead_type; 

}
```

I'd rather not put in all the extra code because it's just a callout and then a bunch of regex and parsing and soql, and it would take a long time to clean out stuff that shouldn't be on the internet.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. Can you post your classes so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @jongpie I added some code, if you need the httprequest and all I can add that too but I didn't want to take too long (and cleaning out private company stuff would take me a bit), the bottom of the code I added are the wrappers that are being ignored

Comment: a simple debug statement or developer console checkpoint could verify that your mock class's respond() method is returning the JSON string you expect to be usable by your deserialization methods

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are facing the same issue as I posted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10018/testing-apex-classes-created-by-jsontoapex) - that de-serializing JSON in a test doesn't create code coverage of the class it is deserialized into...the only way I have got round it was to add getters to each element, and get each one after I have created the class from JSON methods...

Comment: of course! I've seen this problem myself and thanks for reminding me

Comment: So wait, I basically just need to add something like:   `public String comment {get;set;};` to all of my variables and it'll suddenly count them in code coverage?

Comment: I've always had to add a getter, instantiate the class via the JSON parse method JSON2Apex creates, and then do an assert e.g. system.assertequals('This is a comment', myclass.Comment);